# package Build does not exist "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT"

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I want use this repository for create react native app than can run in foreground and background but when I download this repo and want to use this I get this error :

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> C:\Users\PC\Desktop\shem\rn-heartbeat-master\android\app\src\main\java\com\rnheartbeat\BootUpReceiver.java:11: error: package Build does not exist
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

this is my infrastructure :

> Operating system:  Windows 10 10.0
> Max Gradle workers: 12 workers
> Java runtime:   Oracle Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 12.0.2+10
> Java VM:    Oracle Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 12.0.2+10 (mixed mode, sharing)

my build.gradle :

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
```

my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `import android.os.Build;` to your BootUpReceiver.java